# fetchで取得したJSONに対する処理でエラーが発生する

Tags: javascript

次のエラーが出ます。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
test?id=96&date=2021-08-13:282 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: responceData.forEach is not a function
    at
```

**ソースコード:**

```
let huu = fetch(url);
tmp_char = "";
huu.then(response => response.json()).then(
    responceData =>{
        responceData.forEach(element => {
            if(element['numa'] != null ){
                tmp_char +=  element['amount'];
            }
        })
    }
)
```

Comment: レスポンスのJSONも合わせて追記してください。

Comment: [Iterate through an API-array, data.forEach is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55971468)